# login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-login, django-custom-user

Here is my view,

```
def login_view(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          email = form.cleaned_data['email']
          password = form.cleaned_data['password']
          user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

          if user is not None:
              form = LoginForm()
              login(request, user)
```

I get an error:

```
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Also, I am using a custom user model

My `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.register, name='register' ),
path('form',views.form, name = 'form'),
path('login',views.login, name = 'login ')]
```

Comment: Can we see your `urls.py`

Comment: Sure . I’ll add it

Comment: @scharette Please suggest a solution, thanks : )

Comment: You probably overwrote `login` somewhere with another function.

Answer (score 12):

You're not using the right view, try this instead

```
path('login',views.login_view, name = 'login ')
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I forgot to change that. My bad . It is running smoothly now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
path('',views.register, name='register' ),
path('form',views.form, name = 'form'),
path('login/', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

or

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
path('',views.register, name='register' ),
path('form',views.form, name = 'form'),
path('login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

If you are using django's own authentication scheme, the second example will be more accurate.

I actually changed the login path in the url file. I think the error is due to the path connection.
that's path =>

```
path('login',views.login, name = 'login ')]
```

Comment: This answer is confusing. Could you give OP more insights on what is the purpose of your solution ?

Comment: You are correct. The error was in the urls. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Django built in user authentication only accepts username and password to login. You have to change it if you want to log in your user by email and password.

Comment: oh my bad. Did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your function as login_view in views.py but you are calling it as login on urls.py. Try view.login_view.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems that you have a function named login_view defined, but in your URL configuration, you are referring to a function named login. This mismatch in function names is likely causing the error.

Change the function name in your URL configuration to match the view function name,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other URL patterns
    path('login', views.login_view, name='login'),
]
```